# How to fake my identity to my ISP?

Tags: proxy, youtube, isp, broadband

My Broadband internet speed is 512kbps, but
my ISP provides a speed boost when I surf the
Youtube ( or Google drive). 
They provide about 5-6Mbps speed while I'm streaming or Downloading any Youtube video. 
So I can stream HD videos directly.

My question is, "Is there any way to make my
ISP think that, I'm using Youtube even if I
browse/Download from another sites? So that
I can get high speed.

I know there is a proxy related system, but I
don't know the method. Can anybody please
tell me the method for PC?

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this. Your isp knows that youtube's ip address is a certain value and that you are trying to request content from it.

You can't doublespeak and say I want information from youtube and another page at the same time, and there is no way to route information through youtube. Sorry.

Comment: Some people use Front query to do this kinda (not actually this) things.
They use some sites as their front query from those they get some privileges(like 0.facebook.com it's free for browsing) and then use free internet.
How does it work then? 
I'm just asking for educational purposes.